# How can I put two ggplots next to each other and make them NOT occupy the same amount of space (50:50) in rstudio?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to put two ggplots next to each other and I have done that thanks to the great function grid.arrange

```
grid.arrange(p, q, ncol=2)
```

The problem is they both take half of the space (width). But the second graph 'q' should only occupy about one tenth of the space because the y-axis is of a far smaller range than the one from 'p'. How can I do that?
I would take either solution, no matter if manually choosing how much space they take or automatically done by r.

They are both from the same y-axis. 'p' ends in December 2019 and 'q' starts in January 2020 but they should explicitly not share the y-axis (because there are big differences in the x-axis between the two graphs).

Comment: Have a look at the help page for grid.arrange, you'll see you can specify the widths or heights of the graphs - `https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html`

Comment: if faceting worked (i.e. these plots are showing essentially the same x/y variables), then using `scale="free", shape="free"` in a faceting specification might work too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `widths` and `heights` arguments to control such things. The following code use `widths = c(1, 0.1)` to set the width of the second plot to 1/10 of the first.

```
p <- ggplot(data.frame(x = 1, y = 1), aes(x, y))+
  geom_point()

q  <- p

grid.arrange(p, q, ncol=2, widths = c(1, 0.1))
```